# Can you configure Symfony to use XML instead of YAML and annotations?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to implement an API using Symfony/API-Platform and I would like to use XML instead of YAML and annotations. For example when I run `bin/console make:user` to create a user entity, it will be created with doctrine annotations for mapping properties to database fields. What i want is the same functionality but in a XML file.

Is there a possibility to configure symfony to prefer XML configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way to do it, but changing type in mapping configuration to xml may help you. Default file is located [here](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/config/packages/doctrine.yaml#L21) and you need to change type to `xml` and dir to xml mapping path.